# How Can I make Spring-MVC @PropertySources load first, before any other configuration

Tags: spring-mvc, configuration, autowired

I have a spring-mvc application that is using java configuration, not xml.  There are @Configuration annotations sprinkled through several files.  In particular, there is a @PropertySources annotation in one file in a class that implements WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.  There are two classes which contain an @Autowired Environment variable.  One of these classes is itself a @Configuration class, and I would like it to have access to the fully-loaded Environment at the time it runs.

This isn't happening.  When this code executes, the Environment is still null.  I've tried reordering the @ComponentScan packages, tried moving the @PropertySources annotation, and nothing has helped me load the property sources in time.

I want this to happen first, before any other configuration.

What must I do to make it so?

UPDATE: After trying many things, including the Order annotation, I find the problem seems to be not so much that the @PropertySources are being loaded too late as that a class I have that is derived from `org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` is being loaded too soon.  Nothing in my code even references this class but Spring is somehow deciding that this, above all other classes, must be initialized first.  No amount of messing around with @Order seems to change this.  This in spite of the [javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.html#AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer%28java.lang.Class...%29), which indicate that the behavior I want is the default:

> Caveats
>
> Subclasses of AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer will register their
>   filters before any other Filter. This means that you will typically
>   want to ensure subclasses of AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer are
>   invoked first. This can be done by ensuring the Order or Ordered of
>   AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer are sooner than subclasses of
>   AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ContextInitializer, catch the moment when Boot prepared its environment and "inject" your property source programmatically as you want.
If you have a ConfigurableApplicationContext then it provides a ConfigurableEnvironment, which contains the propertySources as a list. If you want your PropertySource to rule all above the others than add it as **first**. If you want to place it to a special position then you can add it **before** an other, identified by its "name".

```
public class ConfigInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {

    // rule over all the others: 
    ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().
      addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource("file:/etc/conf/your_custom.properties"));

    // rule over application.properties but not argument or systemproperties etc
    ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().
      addBefore("applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]",
      new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:your_custom.properties"));

    // names can be discovered by placing a breakpoint somewhere here and watch 
    // ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().propertySourceList members,
    // each has a name ...
    }
}
```

You can bring into play this class by:

- registering it in the *application.properties* :

```
    context.initializer.classes=a.b.c.ConfigInitializer
```

- or from application start :

```
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(YourApplication.class).
      initializers(new ConfigInitializer()).
      run(args);
```

By the way this is a proper way to inject more of your custom properties, like properties coming from a database or a different host etc...

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am an expert in Java config but maybe:

> Spring 4 utilizes this feature in its @PropertySource annotation. To
>   remind you, @PropertySource annotation provides a mechanism for adding
>   a source of name/value property pairs to Spring's Environment and it
>   is used in conjunction with @Configuration classes.

Taken from:  http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/how-to-propertysource-annotations-in.html

1. Are you using @PropertySource or @PropertySources?
2. Have You tried 'order' property for spring bean initialisation?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using PropertySources.  Haven't tried Order yet, trying to think what class to put it on.  May have to move PropertySources into its own class.  Silly SO UI won't let me put At signs on these annotations, thinks I'm trying to ping users named "PropertySources" and "Order".

Comment: I see nothing there that deals with the PropertySources.  No matter what I do, it goes straight into the security config, prematurely.  This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Could You provide code samples (eg. on Github)? I see this question as a nice 'introduction problem' to Java config and would like to deal with it.